# JSPDF how to modify this code to print two pages instead of one page

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a script to generate a DIV to PDF but now I have two DIVs and I need to generate a two-pages PDF from this two DIVs

How can I modify this code to do this

The first DIV is the #pdf-one and the second is #pdf-two

```
public exportHtmlToPDF() {
    let data = document.getElementById('pdf-one')!;

    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {

      let docWidth = 208;
      let docHeight = canvas.height * docWidth / canvas.width;

      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
      let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      let position = 0;
      doc.addImage(contentDataURL, 'JPG', 0, position, docWidth, docHeight, 'FAST');

      doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using break-after on your first div, like this:

```
#pdf-one {
 break-after: always; 
}
```

More info about break-after you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)

And of course your div's height should match the height of the pdf page